# a wrapped image adding space

Tags: html, css

Just like on this example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbefc58t/2/

When I have images wrapped in a link it adds space below the image. How do I get rid of this?

```
<div class="top">
    <a href="/">
        <img src="http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/screen_medium/11/118253/2220255-wolf3d_dos.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

.

```
*{padding:0;margin:0;}
.top{ background: grey; border-radius: 3px; margin: 5px 0; overflow: hidden; }
a{line-hight:0;}
```

Comment: JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sbefc58t/1/

Comment: What is `line-hight`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sbefc58t/1/)**

Use `vertical-align: middle;` to `img`

```
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `display: block` in `img`:

```
img{display: block;}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sbefc58t/8/)

Comment: Do you know what `inherit` really does?

Comment: Do be honest `display: block` is enough http://jsfiddle.net/sbefc58t/8/

Comment: Therefore I'm not sure if the link should fill the entire space of the parent (as a block level element)

Comment: hmm you are right but OP didn't specify it. Thx for feedback @HashemQolami ;) Mary Melody answer is better.